# 'alpha' inside a \def

Tags: macros

the following code

```
\def\AIR{\alphair}
```

results in a compilation error in Texmaker when calling \AIR\ in text:

```
"\textit{\AIR\/}"
! Undefined control sequence.\AIR ->\alphair
```

Where's the problem with MikTex?

Comment: Have you defined `\alphair` elsewhere or is it defined in a package you load? Maybe you misspelled `\alpha`?

Comment: Well, shouldn't he detect the single \alpha in \alphair ? But also, \def\AIR{\alpha} doesn't work, ofc amssymb is used.

Comment: If you write `\alphair` it's considered as one macro, namely the macro named "alphair". Is what you want to write the symbol alpha followed by "i" and "r"? In that case simply add a space to the definition: `\def\AIR{\alpha ir}`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with your definition. The problem is that `\alphair` is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to define

```
\newcommand{\AIR}{$\alpha$\textit{ir}}
```